# How get TextField from custom view use onNodeWithTag if tag on parent box

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-testing, gui-testing

For test UI I use code

```
composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag(usernameFieldTag).performTextInput(testUser)
```

But my Text field is custom and I send testTag in parent view (Column)

```
AppTextField(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,...){
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Row {
            BasicTextField(...)
        }
    }
}
```

And I get error `java.lang.AssertionError: Failed to perform text input.`
I trying use `useUnmergedTree = true` but it not help

Comment: Of course, you can pass the testTag to the parameters and then to BasicTextField. But if not good variant.